# How to convert string in to Array in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I have this string:

```
    var d = [
    '[(not set),20200409,103,0.0]',
    '[(not set),20200410,112,0.0]',
    '[(not set),20200411,56,0.0]',
    '[(not set),20200412,58,0.0]',
    '[(not set),20200413,108,0.0]',
    '[(not set),20200414,91,0.0]'];
```

But I want this type of array by converting the string *d*
it should look like after processing.

```
    var processd_array = [
     ['(not set)',20200409,103,0.0],
     ['(not set)',20200410,112,0.0],
     ['(not set)',20200411,56,0.0],
     ['(not set)',20200412,58,0.0],
     ['(not set)',20200413,108,0.0],
     ['(not set)',20200414,91,0.0] ];
```

How I can do this in Nodejs?

Comment: You should show what you have tried already. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Your string syntax is wrong and also after processing the array syntax is wrong too. You used backticks in wrong places!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's split every element from the `d` array into pieces.

```js
var d= [
  '[(not set),20200409,103,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200410,112,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200411,56,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200412,58,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200413,108,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200414,91,0.0]'];
 
const result = d.map(item => item.split(','));

console.log(result);
```

This works, but it does not get rid of `[]` characters from the beginning and from the end of each line.

Let's fix this:

```js
var d= [
  '[(not set),20200409,103,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200410,112,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200411,56,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200412,58,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200413,108,0.0]',
  '[(not set),20200414,91,0.0]'];

// remove [] characters from a string  
const removeUnwantedCharacters = str => str.replace(/(\[|\])/, '');

const result = d.map(item => item.split(',').map(removeUnwantedCharacters));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation even though question was so unclear

Comment: Thanks, Ervin for your answer your suggested solution worked for me.